# How can I cyclically shift an array without additional heap memory?

Tags: algorithm

How can I write a function `shift(int* arr, int k)` cyclically shift an array by some integer k? I cannot say "malloc" memory from the heap.

For instance, using pseudocode, `shift([1, 2, 3, 4], 2)` returns `[3, 4, 1, 2]`, and `shift([3, 1, 5, 5], 103)` returns `[1, 5, 5, 3]`. I have tried using modulus to achieve this effect, as shown in this Java program, in which I basically iterate through half of the array and swap values.

```
public static int* shift(int* arr, int k) {
  int half_array_len = arr.length / 2;
  for (int i = 0; i < half_array_len; ++i) {
    // Swap!
    int newIndex = (i + k) % arr.length;
    int temp = arr[i];
    arr[i] = arr[newIndex];
    arr[newIndex] = arr[i];
  }
  return arr;
}
```

However, I believe that this function only works for even-lengthed arrays.

How can I implement `shift` for arrays of any length? Answers can be in any language you want (Java, C++, [Ook Ook!](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Ook!), etc.).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

(Has been asked several times before.) Basically, three classic in-place algorithms dedicated to solving this problem are described and analyzed in Bentley's "Programming Pearls" (Juggling, Reversal and Block Swap algorithms). These slides describe them in sufficient detail

http://www.cs.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/pearls/s02b.pdf

The simplest algorithm is the Reversal Algorithm. Simply reverse the entire array and then reverse each [n - k] and [k] block independently. Done. (From which end the [k] block is counted depends on the direction of the shift.)

Of course, it makes sense to normalize the `k` first, i.e, do `k = k % n` to make sure `k` is less than `n`.

P.S. In C++ the answer would be to use `std::rotate`, which does exactly what you want. But I doubt this is the answer you seek. Although you might want to take a look at some implementations of `std::rotate` (if only to discover that they typically use the Reversal algorithm :)

Comment: Wow. I had never even heard of this problem before and the paper you linked to listed the two I wrote as the expensive ones

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you mean that you can only use a constant amount of additional space to perform this function. It can be done with one temp in `O(n*(k mod n))` time using the following algorithm (Python):

```py
def shift_one(array):
    temp = array[-1] #put last element of array in a temp
    for i in range(len(array)-1)[::-1]:
        array[i+1] = array[i] #put each element in the next slot
    array[0] = temp #then put the temp at the beginning
    return array

def shift(array, k):
    for i in range(k%len(array)):
        array = shift_one(array)
    return array
```

If you are not in fact constrained to constant additional space, you can do it with `k` additional space in `O(n)` time with the following algorithm (almost the same thing):

```py
def shift(array, k):
    k = k % len(array) #shifting by len(array) does nothing
    temp = array[-k:] #copy out the last k elements
    for i in range(len(array)-k)[::-1]:
        array[i+k] = array[i]
    array[:k] = temp
    return array
```

Also, if you have lists like in Python that can do a lot more than arrays can, there is a very simple solution:

```py
def shift(array, k):
    #take the last k elements and put them at the front
     return array[-k:]+array[:-k]
```